# WinRT: Get battery information?

Tags: windows-runtime

In WinRT, is there a way to get information about the battery? I.e. similar information that shows in the desktop notification area: time remaining, percent left, percent left, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API available in WinRT - I've been investigating this about a month ago.
As Robin Yang mentioned on MSDN discussion:

> [GetSystemPowerStatus API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used to retrieve the power status of the
>   system. The status indicates whether the system is running on AC or DC
>   power, whether the battery is currently charging, and how much battery
>   life remains.
>
> It seemingly can meet your needs. However, this API applies to
>   "desktop app only".

Comment: Thanks, Martin. That's unfortunate! Wanted to make a little power tile app.

Comment: I'd also like to see something like this available for WinRT apps. It seems that a number of key APIs are not yet available - hopefully they'll be added in future updates.

Answer (score 0):

Its a pity you cant access such info, maybe writing status to local storage in scheduled task is the only option currently :-(

I don't think it a very user friendly way to do it, even it your could get through the store certification.

```
FOR /f %i IN ('whoami') DO set userId=%i    
FOR /f %i IN ('dir /s/b %localappdata%\packages\\localcache ^| find "MyBatteryApp"') DO set appFolder=%i    
echo Return = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("cmd /c ""WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining  > %appFolder%\MyBatteryApp.txt""", 0, true) > %appFolder%\battery.vbs 
echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?^>^<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task"^>^<Triggers^>^<TimeTrigger^>^<Repetition^>^<Interval^>PT15M^</Interval^>^<StopAtDurationEnd^>false^</StopAtDurationEnd^>^</Repetition^>^<StartBoundary^>2014-01-01T00:00:00^</StartBoundary^>^</TimeTrigger^>^<SessionStateChangeTrigger^>^<StateChange^>SessionUnlock^</StateChange^>^<UserId^>%userId%^</UserId^>^</SessionStateChangeTrigger^>^</Triggers^>^<Settings^>^<DisallowStartIfOnBatteries^>false^</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries^>^</Settings^>^<Actions^>^<Exec^>^<Command^>wscript^</Command^>^<Arguments^> //B //nologo %appFolder%\battery.vbs^</Arguments^>^</Exec^>^</Actions^>^</Task^> > %tmp%\batterySetting.xml
schtasks /create /tn "MyBatteryApp" /xml "%tmp%\batterySetting.xml"
```